# SQL LIMIT: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO to retrieve data from php. I am trying to use limit function but sadly it did not work. I searched around the forum for similar questions and found answers similar to what I tried below. But I get the same warning. I am relatively new to PDO. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$limit = 5;
$users = $db->prepare("SELECT code,name from Portion where name LIKE '%$t%' LIMIT :limit");
$users->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$users->execute(['query' => "{$_GET['query']}%"]);
```

Comment: There's no `:query` in your SQL.

Comment: Using PDO != definitely safe from sql injections.

Comment: @Barmar my query works with just line 2 and 4 without limit. I want to add limit to this.

Comment: @TZHX $t = "some string to match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to fill in parameters of a PDO query, you either

- Use `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` to bind them before calling `execute()`, or
- Provide an array of values as an argument to `execute()`.

You can't mix them -- when you supply the array argument, that overrides the `bindParam` settings. Since you're passing an array argument to `execute()` (although for no apparent reason, since there's no `:query` parameter in the SQL), the `:limit` parameter is being lost.

Change your code to:

```
$limit = 5;
$users = $db->prepare("SELECT code,name from Portion where name LIKE CONCAT('%', :pattern, '%') LIMIT :limit");
$users->execute([':pattern' => $t, ':limit' => $limit]);
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it returns an empty set.

$users->fetchAll() returns []

Comment: Now I tried using bindValue instead of passing it as array. And it worked.

Comment: There's no reason why that should make a difference. You must have been doing something else different.